# Facebook Graph API Targeting/Gating and Events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Looking for information on Facebook post targeting. Since Facebook have changed the layout of there documentation they seem to have removed all the useful data. i can no longer find anything on Geo targeting/Gating posts with the graph API.

I know is possible because i am doing it. but i can no longer find the documentation for it.

Has this been depreciated and does anyone know if its possible to add any sorting of geo targeting or news feed targeting to Facebook events through the graph API